# Connect Flat files using java jdbc

Tags: java, excel, csv, jdbc, flat-file

I have a problem with connecting flat files(.txt, .xml, .csv, .xls, etc...) which is existing in application it's self, using jdbc connection.

After searching I found some suggestions below.

1)[xlsql](http://xlsql.sourceforge.net/.)
2)[JDO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135919.html)

I tried with **first one (xlsql)**, below is the process.
First create core java project and load the jar files which is from xlsql.
below is the code

```
Class.forName("com.nilostep.xlsql.jdbc.xlDriver");
final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\db\\xl";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:nilostep:excel:/"+dir);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from  Sheet1$";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
if(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}else{
System.out.println("nodata....");
}
```

It is saying Sheet1$ table not existing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

xlsql's principle is a little complex, it uses hsqldb or mysql as sql engines, creates related databases and tables with data from excels files, then executes queries over the database. It treats:

```
    directory -> database
    excel file -> schema
    sheet -> table
```

so It accesses a table using a schema prefix. for example:

```
    String sql = "select * from \"demo.xlsqly7\"";
```

Here "demo" is the excel file name without extension, xlsqly7 is the sheet name. In "XlSQL-Y8.zip" or "xlsql-Y7.zip" , there is an example "TestXlsql.java". I also wrote another one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.nilostep.xlsql.jdbc.xlDriver");
    String dir = "C:\\Temp\\xlsql-Y7";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:nilostep:excel:"+dir);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from  \"Book1.MergedResult\"";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("nodata....");
    }

}
```

Another constraint is that the first row of a sheet must be column names which must start with a uppercase letter, or the sheet will be considered invalidate.

This is the best document about XLSQL: http://blog.csdn.net/ailvey/article/details/8779119, unfortunately, it is written in Chinese.

Comment: Does xlsql support xlsx files? I think it depends on jxl which doesn't support xlsx files. So, I think xlsx files are not supported by this library. Am I correct?